# Exact scene where we can see Sophie in Whiplash

Tags: character, whiplash

In the movie Whiplash, where is the scene where we can see Kavita Patil? All I know is that she plays a character named Sophie who is the assistant of Terence Fletcher, nevertheless even after going through the screenplay I couldn't find any dialogue exchanges between Sophie and the other characters. Please specify the exact scene where we can see Sophie acting (a.k.a Kavita Patil).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I positively don't remember her on the movie. But I did go through the screen play as you have done and found this small dialogue where Andrew talks with Fletcher's assistant. This scene happens right after the scene where Andrew secures a date with Nicole.

> **ASSISTANT:**
>   Andrew Neiman?
>   (Andrew turns)
>   Dr. Fletcher would like to see you.
>   **ANDREW:**
>   Oh. Ok...

You can find the screenplay I looked at [here](http://www.sonyclassics.com/awards-information/whiplash_screenplay.pdf). The exact part is on the page numbered 12th. The specific scene name is **INT. GEHRING HALL - LOBBY OUTSIDE DEAN'S OFFICE - DAY**. Hope this helps.